# Intel thunderbolt port - can I use it to connect 2 macpros together to get fast networking

Tags: networking, lightpeak, thunderbolt

There is a new fast port from Intel: [Thunderbolt](http://www.intel.com/technology/io/thunderbolt/index.htm)  (was code named *Light Peak*). It provides
Dual-channel Bi-directional 10 Gbps per port. Can I use this port to connect two computers together like with 10Gigabit Ethernet (to create a very fast network between computers)?

Thanks

Comment: In theory, there's probably no reason you can't do something like that the same way there are special USB connectors to do this.  In practice, somebody will actually have to make such a product - I doubt it'll be as straightforward as plugging a standard cable in.  I think the real answer is "Ask again in a few months" since nobody, to my knowledge, is actually manufacturing anything that USES this connection yet!

Comment: @Shanrai, Actually, apple has a preproduction macpros and it must start mass production at the time.

Comment: Thunderbolt Technology Brief PDF...http://www.intel.com/technology/io/thunderbolt/325136-001US_secured.pdf

Comment: I didn't mean the ports.  I meant devices to plug into the ports.  Nobody's making the PERIPHERALS yet - I can't walk into Best Buy and buy a hard drive with a Thunderbolt interface.  Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, the hardware supports this.

In practice, it would require software support. Current Macintosh computers with firewire can mount another computer's storage as a drive volume on boot. I suspect this will be the route Apple takes if they include this feature, rather than using it to create an ad-hoc TCP/IP network.

**UPDATE**

A [Macworld article](http://www.macworld.com/article/158145/2011/02/thunderbolt_what_you_need_to_know.html) by Dan Frakes and Dan Moren states:

> On the new MacBook Pro models, you can use Target Disk Mode over a computer-to-computer Thunderbolt connection. (We assume this will be the case with future Thunderbolt-equipped Macs, as well.) However, Mac OS X’s Migration Assistant software doesn’t currently support Thunderbolt connections.

Comment: Yyyeeesss! Target disk mode is alive again. But using it like network is still interesting.

Comment: Technically this may not fully answer the question. The question was whether or not it could be used "like Ethernet," which introduces far more capabilities than Target disk mode.

Comment: @Josh Yes, no one knows. However in my answer I do address the ethernet issue. I don't think it will be supported.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that it will require software support, which does not appear to be available at this time.